# I am getting my application killed randomly

Tags: c, gtk

In my GTK+ application in C, the following error occurs randomly and my application gets killed:

> `gtk_text_buffer_emit_insert: assertion 'g_utf8_validate (text, len, NULL)' failed`

Please help me if someone else also got the same issue and resolved it.

Follow is an example of what I am doing ,
`

```
char text[1024];
int size = 0;

sprintf(text+0,"Be Still & Please Follow Instructions");
size = strlen((char *)text)
gtk_text_buffer_set_text (GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(text_buff),(char *)text,size);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

This is quite clearly happening because you're inserting text which is failing to validate as UTF-8. Of course we cannot provide more detailed help, since we don't have your code.

Check if you call `gtk_text_buffer_emit_insert()`, or some function which in turn calls that function. Basically, check all places where you pass text to some "big" text-displaying widget.

One way of getting help is of course to add a call to the same validation function yourself, i.e. [`g_utf8_validate()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-validate), then you can print out a message so you can learn which text-insertion is failing, add a breakpoint for your debugger, or whatever.

Comment: No way that code compiles, what is `text.name` supposed to be? Also drop all the casts to `char *`. Also, that snippet can be replaced by `gtk_text_buffer_set_text(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(text_buff), "Be Still & Please Follow Instructions", -1);`, try that and see if it helps.

Comment: sorry that was added by mistake , now i correct it and also I can't simply place text directly as I have different messages to display.

Comment: @M.Shah If this question is no longer valid, please vote to close it, or edit to make it clear that it was not a real problem. Post a new question for the new problem.

Comment: This is the real problem and i still not get the right answer for what i am looking , i can't put the whole code here due to privacy policy of my company , thats why I added an example simply to understand which I am asking.

Comment: @M.Shah Yes, okay, fine. What happened when you investigated all the locations where text is being inserted? You can of course add your own calls to the validation function before calling the text widget, to track down where the broken text is being handed to GTK+.

Comment: I didn't found any bug and also tell how can i check the validation before calling text widget?

Comment: @M.Shah Like I said, by adding a call to [`g_utf8_validate()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-validate) yourself.

Comment: I have solved my bug, thank you all for supporting and help.

Comment: @M.Shah - can you please share how did you solve your bug?